# "Can't read property call of undefined" error on JSBin?

Tags: reactjs, jsbin

I am trying to learn React using JSBin. I have simple example code `BookList` and `BookInfo` (renders items inside BookList).

http://jsbin.com/hoyeroz/2/edit?js,output

I am getting below error in the console:[image]

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

Is this a JSBin bug or am I declaring the React components incorrectly?

Comment: You are better off pasting your actual errors and your actual code here.  Pictures of errors and links to code are not helpful for searching or for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is proper, and working also, don't know why it is not working on `JSBin`, because same code is giving proper output on `jsfiddle`.

check `fiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/03Lm3zbv/

**Update**: After doing some Google search finally got this:

This is a bug with `JSBin`, and how it handles transpilation with Babel. If you add the pragma `//noprotect` to the top of your code it will work.

check the working code on `JSBin`: http://jsbin.com/gedavinodu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit `bind` call here.  So what's not bound?  Well, if you put this in your `compontentDidMount`, you'll see that you get the result you are looking for.

```
    this.setState({ books: [{"body": "body text", "name": "the name"}]});
```

So the ajax call is failing.  This seems suspect: `$.ajax`.  It seems to me that the `$` is not bound to the jQuery function you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to debug.